# Typescript - Types of parameters 'artifact' and 'value' are incompatible

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I am trying to map over an array response from my API in Vue JS and I am getting a typescript error when doing so. Here is my code:

```
 methods: {
      export interface WebspaceBackupArtifact {
          readonly date?: string;
          readonly name?: string | null;
          readonly path?: string | null;
          readonly type?: string | null;
      }
    
      interface WebspaceBackupArtifactExtended extends WebspaceBackupArtifact {
        size?: number;
        type?: string;
      }

      let artifacts = [] as WebspaceBackupArtifactExtended[];
      if (response?.data?.artifacts) {
        artifacts = response.data.artifacts
          .map((artifact: WebspaceBackupArtifactExtended) => ({
            ...artifact,
            date: moment(artifact.date!).format('DD-MMM-YYYY'),
          }))
          .sort(
            (
              a: WebspaceBackupArtifactExtended,
              b: WebspaceBackupArtifactExtended,
            ) => a.type!.localeCompare(b.type!),
          );
      }
  }
```

produces the following error:

```
ERROR in /app/src/views/BackupAndRestore/BackupAndRestoreWebspaceBackup.vue(594,16):
my-project    | 594:16 Argument of type '(artifact: WebspaceBackupArtifactExtended) => { date: string; size?: number | undefined; type?: string | undefined; name?: string | null | undefined; path?: string | null | undefined; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: WebspaceBackupArtifact, index: number, array: WebspaceBackupArtifact[]) => { date: string; size?: number | undefined; type?: string | undefined; name?: string | ... 1 more ... | undefined; path?: string | ... 1 more ... | undefined; }'.
my-project    |   Types of parameters 'artifact' and 'value' are incompatible.
my-project    |     Type 'WebspaceBackupArtifact' is not assignable to type 'WebspaceBackupArtifactExtended'.
my-project    |       Types of property 'type' are incompatible.
my-project    |         Type 'string | null | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'.
my-project    |           Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'.
my-project    |     592 |       if (response?.data?.artifacts) {
my-project    |     593 |         artifacts = response.data.artifacts
my-project    |   > 594 |           .map((artifact: WebspaceBackupArtifactExtended) => ({
my-project    |         |                ^
my-project    |     595 |             ...artifact,
my-project    |     596 |             date: moment(artifact.date!).format('DD-MMM-YYYY'),
my-project    |     597 |           }))
```

I have tried looking at other similar questions that have a similar error message but didn't manage to extract any valuable information that would help me in this case so I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Am I maybe extending the interface wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is saying that you have a callback which requires a `WebspaceBackupArtifactExtended` but your `response.data.artifacts` array is an `array` of `WebspaceBackupArtifact`.

The extended version is assignable to the base version, but not vice-versa.  The specific reason is the property `type`.  `WebspaceBackupArtifact` allows `string | null` while `WebspaceBackupArtifactExtended` only allows `string`.

`response.data.artifacts` is not given a type in the code that you've provided, but I can tell that it is `WebspaceBackupArtifact[] | undefined` based on the error message.  One thing you can do is remove the `WebspaceBackupArtifactExtended` annotations in your `map` and `sort` callbacks and let it be inferred from the array type.

You might also want to think about how to better handle handle instances where `.date` and `.type` are not defined rather than asserting that they will be defined.